# Reading Arabic from SQL Server to R

Tags: r, sql-server, utf

I am having a problem when reading data from SQL Server to R using RODBCext. The Arabic is Displayed as "????????".  I tried to use the DBMSencoding = "UTF-8" and didn't work either.

[image]

The database collation is "Arabic_CI_AS".

Is there anyway to fix this problem properly.

Comment: What is the type of the problematic column?

Comment: It is "nvarchar".

Comment: Please show us the result of select unicode(left(col,1)) , here col is the name of your column. We need it to understand if there are "?" **in the table** or it's transformed otherwhere

Comment: Here it is.  https://imgur.com/a/S41ZT